# Bounty expiry notification message need to improve

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/258/bountymsg.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/258/bountymsg.png)

1. It's not my question, so it should be "the" or something else, instead of "your"
2. I have already awarded the bounty last month (June), so "expires in next 24 hours" is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent point, checking in the change now. I used devinb's suggested text. Thanks guys.

Comment: Fix confirmed -- just got the proper message on my bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

"Your bounty on question XYZ expires in the next SomeNum hours." [x]